# Issue while creating pdf from html

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, xmlworker

I want to convert multiple html's to one PDF. I used the  below code to create pdf . This code is creating an empty PDF with no contents.

```
    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
    ar.add(/resources/html1.html);

    String outputFile =" C:/WholePDF.pdf";
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
    document.open();
    for (String htmlfile : ar) {
        String html = Utilities.readFileToString(htmlfile);
        ElementList list = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(html, null);
        for (Element e : list) {
            document.add(e);
        }
        document.newPage();
    }
    document.close();
```

Comment: This question is unanswerable without seeing the content of `html1.html`. Many different examples on the [official web site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/parsing-xml-and-xhtml) prove that the code that is shown works correctly with correct HTML that contains tags and CSS that are supported by XML Worker (but be aware that not all tags and not all CSS attributes are supported).

Comment: Please read this article to find out why the two questions you've posted on StackOverflow don't get an answer: http://blog.safedk.com/technology/technologythe-hitchhikers-guide-to-stackoverflow/